# LINQ: How to force a value based reference?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to provide a set of filters for a user to pick from, and each filter will correspond to an `Expression<Func<X, bool>>`.   So, I might want to take a dynamic list of available items ('Joe', 'Steve', 'Pete', etc), and create a collection of "hard-coded" filters based on those names, and let the user select which filter(s) he wants to use.  My problem is that even when I try to "hard-code" my expression based on a string value from the dynamic list, the expression is still storing the value as, what looks to me, a property hanging off of an anonymous type (and I don't know how to serialize the anon. type).   Sorry if this is confusing, I'm not quite sure how to articulate this.

Here's my sample code:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo[] source = new Foo[]
            {
                new Foo() { Name = "Steven" } ,
                new Foo() { Name = "John" } ,
                new Foo() { Name = "Pete" },
            };

            List<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>> filterLst = new List<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>();
            foreach (Foo f in source)
            {
                Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> exp = x => x.Name == f.Name;
                filterLst.Add(exp);
            }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I look at when I look at the body of my expression, it reads as follows:

```
(x.Name = value(ConsoleApplication1.Program+<>c__DisplayClass3).value)
```

When what I really want is for the first one to read like this:

```
(x.Name = "Steven")
```

(if I change my code to this, instead, that's exactly what I get:

```
      Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> exp = x => x.Name == "Steven";
```

)

I've tried forcing my value to a local string value before sticking it into the Expression, but it doesn't seem to help:

```
    List<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>> filterLst = new List<Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>();
    foreach (Foo f in source)
    {
        string value = f.Name;
        Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> exp = x => x.Name == value;
        filterLst.Add(exp);
    }
```

I don't understand why (or really even how) it's still looking at some anonymous type even once I'm using a local variable that is declared to a string.   Is there a way to make this work as I want it to?

Comment: (updated answer to show expression-tree building)

Comment: Are you simplifying a more complex scenario for us? There are easier ways to filter on an array of object properties.

Comment: @Jonas : yes, I've simplified my actual scenario quite a bit.   I'm not really looking to always filter the Name property against a constant string; I'm actually dealing with more complex objects, and I'm providing the user several collections of "filters" that may be based on different properties or multiple property conditions.   Ultimately,though, all of these "filters" are abstracted to the same object type (Expression<Func<X,bool>), which I add to an IQueryable source list to ultimately generate a query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anon-type is actually the compiler-generated type it is using to perform *capture* of the variables. With *delegates* you can hack around this by implementing the capture by hand, but not with lambda expressions compiled to expression-trees.

Two choices:

- build the expression tree explicitely on code via Expression.Constant etc
- learn how to handle the anon types

The latter isn't too bad actually; they are just MemberExpression typically, although I have some code kicking around that covers this in full detail. I can also provide examples of buildin the expression tree, but I'm not at a PC at the moment and it doesn't lend itself well to iPod typing...

From a *brief* read of the question I'd look at the first option more than the second.

Oh, and watch out; the **first** foreach code in the question looks susceptible to the notorious l-value capture issue ;)

---

Edit: I found a PC ;p

```
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "x");
        var body = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Name"),
            Expression.Constant(f.Name, typeof(string)));

        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(body, param);
        filterLst.Add(exp);
```

Comment: This looks like what I need to be doing, but I was hoping to take the lambda and just generate this directly...I guess a little work won't kill me:)   What is the notorious I-Value capture issue?

Comment: @Steven - in the first code-block you give, I *expect* you'll find all 3 filter against `"Pete"`. Because you are capturing the *variable* (not the *value* of the variable), and the loop-variable is declared (technically) *outside* the loop, and is there-fore shared between all 3 expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had to think about that for a bit, but I think I understand.   If I'm right, then the problem is that I've assumed each iteration will get a different version of this: value(ConsoleApplication1.Program+<>c__DisplayClass3) (maybe __DisplayClass4, __DisplayClass5?), but that reference points back to my one "f" reference, which, once the loop is done, will always have a name of "Pete".   I wouldn't have noticed that until it had long since bit me, so I appreciate the warning.

Comment: @Steven - yes, that is exactly it.

Answer (score 4):

Marc Gravell's answer is correct, and here's how you'd implement his first choice:

```
var filters = 
    from f in source
    let param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo),"x")
    select Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(param, "Name"),
            Expression.Constant(f.Name)), param);
```

But this typically isn't necessary. Your second example of the for loop should work with all major LINQ providers. Is there a reason you need the expression to use constants?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after I posted. :P

Comment: I still gave you props for your effort ;)

Comment: @SW : I should have read your post a bit more carefully.   It raises a good question.   In my tests, I was running into serialization problems when dealing with a collection of "filters," and it continued to run into problems even after I tried the second approach on only the first of the items being added.   I guess I was careless in assuming that the same serialization error meant the error was occurring in the same spot....Taking the second approach might have fixed more than I realized. (I've already swapped over to the approach suggested above, so I'm not sure how to easily test that).

Comment: @Steven: So you're serializing the expressions?

Comment: @SW: yes, I probably didn't make that very clear.   I should have probably mentioned that I've been doing all of this locally, just fine...and I had tested the serialization/deserialization of a request object, and it worked fine, but when I tried to do this over a web service, that's when I ran into problems.   My (de)serialization tests just tested against the "simple" lambda of (x => true)...which was probably on-par with the "real" ones, except that they are looking to variables instead of contants...that's when I ran into ser. problems with the "__DisplayClass" stuff.